# Instagram API Not Valid Access TOken

Tags: api, rest, token, instagram

I am new user of Instagram API and I have configured my app as described in the Instagram API documentation, but when I send a request for an Access Token, the access token received is valid to get user information, but not to get feeds, it give me 404 error.

Regards.

Comment: can you copy/paste the information given by the API? are you using the correct endpoint?

Comment: it return the hatml of this page : https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?count=20000&access_token=2284449038.5c1f102.386eb5da2ea0451b9ff2048baadd4dfa

Comment: @Youssef Please note that you've posted your secret access token publicly, and it should not be considered secure anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to one of their lasts updates. Please read [this](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/).

> Deprecation of /users/self/feed

As explained [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_self), You should use this endpoint:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

So the solution for you, will be this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=2284449038.5c1f102.386eb5da2ea0451b9ff2048baadd4dfa
```